# Interesting (known?) polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials

For positive integers $n$, this family of polynomials seems to have interesting properties (i.e. irreducible over $\mathbb{ Z,Q}$, only real and negative roots,...)$$\frac{1}{(n+1) !} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n / 2\rfloor} \frac{(2 n-k) !}{k !(n-2 k) !} X^{k}$$
Any idea where these come from?

Per Dietrich Burde's comment below I add the first few values
\begin{align*}
  &1 \\
  &X + 2\\
&5(X + 1) \\
&3X^2 + 21X + 14\\
&14(2X^2 + 6X + 3)\\
&6(2X^3 + 30X^2 + 55X + 22)\\
&33(5X^3 + 30X^2 + 39X + 13)\\
&55(X^4 + 26X^3 + 91X^2 + 91X + 26)\\
&143(7X^4 + 70X^3 + 168X^2 + 136X + 34)\\
&13(21X^5 + 840X^4 + 4760X^3 + 8568X^2 + 5814X + 1292)\\
&442(14X^5 + 210X^4 + 798X^3 + 1140X^2 + 665X + 133)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Certainly you have computed some examples for $n=1,2,3,4$?

Comment: Yes. And for more values of $n$.

Comment: I added in the main post.

Comment: "Any idea where these come from?" Well where did you get them from?

Comment: Also, $5(x+1)$ is NOT irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Sil Of course, but over $\mathbb Q$. I found stumbled upon these without any indication of origin and/or application.

Comment: I was reacting to the "... to have interesting properties (i.e. irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, ..." in your post. And where did you stumble upon them? You must surely know at least that.

Comment: @Sil, talking to a colleague. I asked him, nothing.